# Form post back Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to postback my infopath form, I have used the below code for the postback, this makes my form too slow to load, is there any other solution for infopath form post back

```
window.onload = function() 
{
window.setTimeout(getData, 1000);
}

function getData()
{
window.setTimeout(getData, 1000); //To handle InfoPath's form postback
}
```

Comment: Please, add full code example. Better will be if you create a jsfiddle or codepen example.

Comment: I just need the code for form postback, which i have set window.setTimeout(getData,1000); like this, is there anyother solution, because the above code making my form load slow, this cannot be seen in jsfiddle -@Pinal

Answer (score 0):

if you want submit after 1 second like you do now you could just use this?

```
window.onload = function() 
{
    window.setTimeout(getData, 1000);
}

function getData()
{
    $("#IdOfYourFormTag").submit();
}
```